# During self introduction, how do I say "I am an Indian" or "I am from India"?

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, indications-de-lieu, géographie

I am a French language beginner from India. When I introduce myself, how do I say "I am an Indian" or "I am from India"? The books I learn from are giving for other nationalities but not mine. I need some help.

Comment: Follow-up question: [*Je viens d'Inde* or *Je viens de l'Inde*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne)? (Mind that neither is very idiomatic, *je suis originaire d'Inde* (or *de l'Inde*?) is better.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can go with many sentences like:

- Je suis indien (indienne for the feminine) [I am an Indian]
- Je viens d'Inde [I come from India]
- Je suis originaire d'Inde [~= I am from India]
- Je suis né(e) en Inde [I was born in India]

And if you are still a citizen of India:

- Je suis de nationalité Indienne [I have Indian nationality]
- Je suis citoyen(ne) d'Inde [I am a citizen of India]

Comment: What about «Je vien de l'Inde»?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora When I read *Je viens de l'Inde*, I initially corrected to *Je viens d'Inde*. Then I thought again and agreed with *Je viens de l'Inde*. Then I thought some more and [became confused](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne).

Answer (score 9):

You can either use "Je suis indien / indienne", or, if you want to avoid confusion with Native Americans, "Je viens d'Inde".

Answer (score 1):

Au Québec, on a inventé le terme "Amérindien" (Indien d'Amérique) ce qui, théoriquement, devrait empêcher la confusion entre les deux provenances possibles pour les "Indiens". Mais ce terme n'est pas utilisé par tous. À remarquer, que plusieurs utilisent à mauvais escient "Hindou" alors qu'ils veulent parler des "Indiens de l'Inde".

Comment: +1 for daring to mention the continued misuse of “Hindou” in this context.  Even my trusty “Le Robert” (granted, the 1998 edition) makes this over-generalization by blanketly equating India, Indians, and all things indian to the civilization and practitioners of Brahmanism under its entry for “hindou/e.”   Although perhaps not as ‘dated’ (read offensive) as the inclusion of “Peaux-Rouges” under its entry for “indien/ne,” I do take it as another sign that it’s obviously time for me to get a new edition, just as it’s obviously long overdue for the Washington Redskins to get a new name.

Comment: Why are you even discussing Quebec??

Answer (score -1):

"Je viens de l'Inde" is what has been taught to me

Comment: Sorry but _Je viens de l'Inde_ is incorrect in French.

Answer (score -2):

certainly do NOT say Je suis d'Inde although I fancy je suis de l;Inde is not impossible.  There is I think a tendency to say "de l'Inde" rather than "d'Inde" (with venir too) because of what you might call the "turkey" factor.

Comment: Absolutely not true. "De l'Inde" is not correct, and generaly "de + le" does not exist. "De + le" = "du", and "de + l' " = "d' ". So definitely say "d'Inde". And what are you calling the "turkey" factor ?

Comment: "d'Inde" sounds like "dinde", which is the word for "turkey". At least, that's what I think he meant to say.