# « Je viens d'Allemagne » ou « je viens de l'Allemagne » ?

Tags: articles, indications-de-lieu, géographie

> [Je viens d'Allemagne](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+d%27Allemagne%22&tbm=bks) (2). [Je viens de l'Allemagne](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+de+l%27Allemagne%22&tbm=bks) (4).
> [Je viens d'Angleterre](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+d%27Angleterre%22&tbm=bks) (2). [Je viens de l'Angleterre](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+de+l%27Angleterre%22&tbm=bks) (6).
> [Je viens d'Inde](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+d%27Inde%22&tbm=bks) (2). [Je viens de l'Inde](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+de+l%27Inde%22&tbm=bks) (8).
> [Je viens d'Iran](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+d%27Iran%22&tbm=bks) (8). [Je viens de l'Iran](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+de+l%27Iran%22&tbm=bks) (1).
> [Je viens d'Uruguay](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+d%27Uruguay%22&tbm=bks) (1). [Je viens de l'Uruguay](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22je+viens+de+l%27Uruguay%22&tbm=bks) (1).

Avec un nom de pays féminin qui commence par une consonne, on ne met jamais d'article : « je viens de France », « je viens de Chine », etc. (sauf si le pays est qualifié : « je viens de la Russie profonde »). Avec un nom de pays masculin qui commence par une consonne, on met toujours l'article : « je viens du Canada », « je viens du Danemark », etc.

Lorsque le nom du pays commence par une voyelle, j'ai spontanément tendance à ne pas mettre d'article, mais la présence d'un article me choque plus ou moins suivant les cas. Si je change « je viens » en « je suis originaire » (qui a le même sens) ou en « je reviens » (qui ressemble bigrement et devrait se construire pareil), mon intuition change parfois ! Et quand j'arrive à l'Inde, je trouve « je viens d'Inde » étrange (peut-être à cause de l'allitération sur le `d` ?), mais « je suis originaire de l'Inde » me choque alors que « je reviens de l'Inde » ne me choque pas. Par contre « je viens de l'Andalousie » me choque (malgré le `d`).

En introduction de cette question, j'ai cité quelques exemples, avec entre parenthèses leur nombre d'occurrences sur Google Books. Entre le nombre non statistiquement significatif d'occurrences et le fait que cette phrase a tendance à être énoncée par des locuteurs non natifs, ces données ne m'informent pas beaucoup.

Jean Bastin, dans ses [*Études philologiques sur la langue française, ses origines, ses principales formes grammaticales*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=d4w7AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22je+viens+de+l%27Angleterre%22) (qui date de 1870) cite les deux possibilités sans détail et admet l'article pour les noms féminins commençant par une consonne, ce qui me semble désuet (p. 21–22) :

> On a essayé de faire une différence entre : je viens de l'Angleterre et je viens d'Angleterre. Cette différence n'a aucun fondement.
>
> Avec les noms masculins de pays, nous disons : je viens du Danemark, du Hanovre, […] etc. ; avec les noms féminins, nous disons plus souvent : je viens de France que je viens de la France. Avec les noms de pays peu connus, au contraire, nous employons mieux l'article : je viens de la Chine, de la Louisiane, de la Tartarie, de la Perse.

Aucune mention d'un cas particulier lorsque le nom du pays commence par une voyelle, pourtant dans ce cas je n'ai pas l'impression que l'usage soit uniforme, ni qu'il soit lié le genre.

Alors, je (re)viens d(e l)'Allemagne ? d(e l)'Angleterre ? d(e l)'Inde ? d(e l)'Iran ? d(e l')Uruguay ? d(e l)'Île-de-France ? d(e l)'Andalousie ? d(e l)'Afrique ? d(e l)'Afrique du Sud ?

Comment: Mais on vient **des États-Unis** et non _d'États-Unis_

Comment: @rds Mauvais contre-exemple : c'est masculin. Mais c'est vrai qu'on utilise aussi l'article (fusionné avec la préposition) pour les noms féminins pluriels : « des (Îles) Salomon ».

Answer (score 12):

D'abord le [récapitulatif](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#58_strong-em-noms-gographiques-et-leurs-articles-em-strong) de l'*Académie française* :

> Les noms de pays s’utilisent généralement avec l’article (*la France*,
>   *l’Allemagne*) ; cependant, il existe quelques exceptions comme *Israël*,
>   *Monaco*, *Madagascar*, *Cuba*, *Taïwan* ou encore *Haïti*.
>
> L’article disparaît toujours avec la préposition « en » (*en France*).
>   Il disparaît également après la préposition « de » indiquant l’origine
>   : *un tapis d’Iran*, *un vase de Chine*. C’est surtout une question
>   d’usage, et il n’y a pas de règle absolue, bien qu’il existe parfois
>   une nuance de sens plus ou moins nette : par exemple, dans *le
>   gouvernement de la France* ou *l’économie de la France*, la France est
>   désignée à un moment de son histoire, tandis que dans *l’ambassade de
>   France*, elle, est prise dans un sens intemporel.
>
> Toutefois, l’article se maintient généralement lorsque le nom qui
>   précède le pays est accompagné d’un adjectif : *l’Histoire de France*
>   mais *l’Histoire économique de la France*.

On note aussi l'usage selon le sens avec l'origine et la dichotomie entre le *moment de l'histoire* par opposition au *sens intemporel*. Cela participe aussi, à mon avis, de la différence dont traite l'auteur *Jean Bastien* et à laquelle on fait référence ici et là dans les réponses.

---

On trouve au *Guichet du savoir* des [contenus](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/search.php?keywords=pays%20pr%C3%A9position&st=0&author=&submit=Rechercher) qui traitent de la question et on fait référence par exemple à un [document](http://www.fabgerard.com/gram/preposition/PrepLieu.htm) sur les *prépositions de lieu*. Pour mettre en scène la règle spécifique sur l'origine, on fait le choix de poser d'abord le genre des noms de pays comme généralité et d'admettre des exceptions, pour fins d'application avec *en* :

> Tous les pays qui se terminent en -e sont féminins.
>  Attention 1 :
>   le Mexique, le Cambodge, le Zaïre, le Zimbabwe, le Mozambique
>   Attention 2 : en Israël, en Iran, en Irak

...puis avec *au* (on note *aux* pour les noms aux pluriel) :

> Tous les pays qui ne se terminent pas en -e + le Mexique, le Cambodge,
>   le Zaïre, le Zimbabwe.

Enfin on traite de l'*origine* en fonction du genre qu'on a posé :

> - Devant les noms de pays féminins : de
>    *ce sont des vins de
>     France*
> - Devant les noms masculin: du
>    *il est du Sénégal*
> - Devant les noms pluriel: des
>    *Vous êtes des États-Unis?*
> - Élision
>    *Ce sont des oranges d'Israël*
>
> [ [*Les prépositions de lieu*](http://www.fabgerard.com/gram/preposition/PrepLieu.htm), site de Fabienne Gérard, extraits (3) ]

---

Dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, *ed. de Boeck/Duculot*), on affirme d'abord généralement au §1051 a)1 (voir en complément, [*départements*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14050)) que les noms de pays prennent la préposition *en* quand ils sont féminins *ou* qu'ils commencent avec une voyelle, et *au* quand ils sont masculins *et* à initiale consonantique. On note aussi qu'auparavant on employait *à la/à l'* plutôt que *en* pour les noms de pays féminins et lointains; qu'on employait même sans article avec les régions (*Ma fille est partie pour Provence*., Sévigné). Par ailleurs, *en Danemark*, *en Canada* restaient possibles, mais rarement, au 20<sup>e</sup>. Ensuite on a des exceptions; *Monaco* et *Saint-Martin* prennent la préposition *à*. Avec les noms de pays dont l'usage de l'article n'est pas constant (par ex. *Andorre*), on a des hésitations entre *en* et *à*.

Et donc on se doit d'aller voir en amont le cas de *l'absence de l'article devant le nom propre* (§588). En principe les noms propres se passent facilement de l'article; c'est le cas des villes et [îles](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3913) etc., avec un tas de nuances, mais ce n'est pas le cas du nom de pays. Dans certains de ces cas on a l'article indéfini.

Quant au cas des régions, dont celui du *pays*, on a ordinairement l'*article défini*. Cependant :

- Les noms pays ne prennent pas l'article quand on utilise *en* (en Iran, en France)
- Quand *de* marque l'origine avec des noms *singuliers* soit *féminins*
  soit *commençant par une voyelle*, on n'utilise pas l'article (on donne
  parmi les exemples *revenir d'Amérique*, *d'Irak*, *les vins d'Espagne*, et celui de *l'ambassade de France* qu'on oppose au
  *gouvernement de la France*)

Puis dans un note on explique que pour les noms féminins, et les masculins qui commencent par une consonne, l'article est « *assez souvent facultatif », surtout après un pluriel (*les côtes de (la) France*). Étrangement on propose un cas au singulier où on montre les deux possibilités: *une carte d'(ou de l')Iran*. Le pépin est que l'Iran est un nom masculin qui commence par une voyelle et non pas par une consonne(!).

---

À la [*Banque de dépannage linguistique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3897) (BDL), on résume la règle sur l'emploi des prépositions avec les noms de pays :

> on emploie la préposition en devant les noms de pays de genre féminin
>   et devant tous les noms qui commencent par une voyelle (ou un h muet).
>   [...]
>  Pour les noms de genre masculin et qui commencent par une
>   consonne (ou un h aspiré), on emploie au, c’est-à-dire à + le.

De plus, on a une [liste](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=143) de tous les noms de pays avec des informations pertinentes dont le *genre*, le *nom officiel* du pays et l'emploi de la *préposition* adéquate (en/au) :

```
Allemagne, fém. / République fédérale d’Allemagne / Allemand, Allemande / Je visiterai l’Allemagne. J’irai en Allemagne.

Royaume-Uni, masc. / Royaume-Uni de Grande-Bretagne et d’Irlande du Nord / Britannique / Je visiterai le Royaume-Uni; la Grande-Bretagne; l’Écosse; l’Angleterre; le Pays de Galles; l’Irlande du Nord. J’irai au Royaume-Uni; en Grande-Bretagne; en Écosse; en Angleterre; au Pays de Galles; en Irlande du Nord.

Inde, fém. / République de l’Inde / Indien, Indienne / Je visiterai l’Inde. J’irai en Inde.

Iran, masc. / République islamique d’Iran / Iranien, Iranienne / Je visiterai l’Iran. J’irai en Iran.

Uruguay, masc. / République orientale de l’Uruguay / Uruguayen, Uruguayenne / Je visiterai l’Uruguay. J’irai en Uruguay.
```

On n'étaye pas quel serait le résultat de l'emploi avec *de* pour signifier l'origine dans ces listes. Cependant, on note un cas [particulier](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3286) avec Haïti (*Cet écrivain est originaire d’Haïti*.); on remarque que l'élision va dans le sens du nom officiel (*République d’Haïti*).

---

Si on tente d'appliquer cette théorie (verbe revenir = origine, + féminin ou débutant par une voyelle), on obtient les mêmes résultats que dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7509) (tous avec *d'*). Dans le cas de l'Inde et de l'Uruguay, ça ne respecte pas le nom officiel du pays (République de l'Inde/orientale de l'Uruguay), même s'il s'agit d'un cas un peu différent du nom rarissime qu'est *Haïti*.

On retient le traitement différent selon qu'on a un verbe signifiant l'origine, et la difficulté d'analyser en vase clos sans faire appel aux règles sur l'affinité des noms de pays avec les prépositions *au* et *en*. Dans la question, quand on discute de l'Inde, on dit qu'on réagit différemment à *être originaire de* vs. *revenir*; au *LBU* on produit des exemples avec revenir pour l'origine, et donc on ne dispose pas ainsi d'une nuance entre l'origine ontologique pourrait-on dire, et l'origine récente, me semble-t-il; ça semble être davantage dans le sens de *provenir* généralement. Mais on reste un peu sur sa faim; peut-être en effet y a-t-il ici une explication de ces réactions qui dépasse le cadre de la grammaire.

Comment: @Ryan Kavanagh Hey, merci !

Comment: Nice references and explanation for the synchronic view of it! The diachronic angle for another question: there's the reference to "*l'absence* de l'article devant le nom propre"... ah, but the question is, why was it ever *present* for countries in the first place? ;) It's not there in Latin (of course), nor in Spanish, Italian, Portuguese, Romanian, nor for that matter in English, German, or Dutch. And it stands to reason: these are proper names. What precisely does the definite article contribute? I may have to formulate a question on this soon.

Answer (score 7):

J'avoue que je n'avais jamais fait attention à cette règle (je réalise du même coup que pour un étranger apprenant le français ce genre de distinction doit être un caprice linguistique un peu épineux), mais ne serait-ce que pour comparer nos considérations euphoniques, je les classerais comme ceci :

(**en gras** ce qui me parait euphonique, *en italique* ce qui me choque/gêne)

> *Je viens de l'Allemagne* | **Je viens d'Allemagne**
>
> *Je viens de l'Inde* | **Je viens d'Inde**
>
> *Je viens de l'Uruguay* | **Je viens d'Uruguay**
>
> **Je viens du Canada** | *Je viens de Canada*
>
> *Je viens de l'Andalousie* | **Je viens d'Andalousie**
>
> *Je viens de l'Afrique* | **Je viens d'Afrique**

Personnellement, cependant, je n'ai pas d'exemple de nom de pays commençant par une voyelle qui me semble échapper à la règle. A part la répétition éventuelle du son *d* que tu mentionnes, effectivement, mais qui ne me semble pas assez gênante pour empêcher l'emploi des expressions *Je viens d'Inde* ou *Je viens d'Odessa*.

Mais peut-être ne voulais-tu pas ce genre de réponse assez subjective ?

Comment: Tout pareil, j'aime pas les articles, sauf s'ils sont contractés avec la préposition, et sauf pour l'Inde pour laquelle j'aurais tendance à l'ajouter tout le temps (à l'oral). Je conçois l'ajout de l'article comme une volonté d'ajouter du relief.

Comment: Effectivement, je cherche plus qu'un avis de locuteur natif, je suis capable d'en donner un tout seul. Je cherche plutôt une analyse du même type que l'ouvrage que j'ai cité, qui est malheureusement incomplet et me semble obsolète.

Comment: @Gilles Oui, je m'en doutais à moitié, attendons des avis plus qualifiés. Et j'avoue que le sujet m'intéresse ausi en partie car je vais intégrer cette construction dans mon générateur de phrases...

Comment: Pour un résumé situé dans le cadre d'une analyse plus moderne, voir Rowlet (2007), "The Syntax of French", pp. 43-44. http://usir.salford.ac.uk/1355/1/Rowlett_The_syntax_of_French_ms.pdf

Answer (score 4):

C'est peut-être un problème d'humour :

*Je reviens d'Inde*, en jouant avec les mots peut s'entendre : *je deviens dinde*, donc le *l'* s'impose pour empêcher cette possibilité.

De même avec *Perse* et le verbe *percer*.

Il y a aussi le phénomène d'apprentissage : qu'un enfant me dise *tu viens de l'Italie ?*, ne me choque pas, pour deux raisons :

- Il respecte scrupuleusement la construction primitive des phrases
- L'Italie peut être, pour lui, un pays éloigné, imaginaire, merveilleux.

Mais je tiquerais un peu sur l'ironie sous-jacentes de cette même phrase employée par un ami lettré.

En effet, Jean Bastin pointe la notoriété du pays cité : si l'on s'efforce de préciser par *le, la, l'* c'est que l'on suppose que la personne à qui l'on parle ne sais pas où se situe ce pays, ou qu'il est rarement mentionné dans les médias.

---

*Complément*

> Je viens d'Allemagne **`.`**

L'entité, ici le pays, l'identité nationale est l'Allemagne

> Je viens de l'Allemagne du nord **`.`**

On indique une région *de* l'Allemagne, l'Allemagne englobant de nombreuses zones géographiques.

Charles Trenet  ne chante pas "Douce *la* France / Cher pays de mon enfance / ...", car il parle du *pays* cher à son cœur, pays partagé par tous les Français.
Mais on pourrait chanter "*La* France que j'aime se trouve dans ton regard", car il s'agit d'une *image singulière* de la France, image liée à une histoire particulière.

Comment: @YohannV. C'est celle du 5e § de la question.

Answer (score 3):

Bon, je tente ma chance.

Selon le contexte donné, selon moi :

« d'Allemagne » est généralement à utiliser lorsqu'il s'agit, par exemple, du notre pays d'origine.

Tandis que « de l'Allemagne » serait quant à lui plus "temporaire".
Comme par exemple « Je (re)viens de l'Allemagne (par exemple, j'y suis allé ce matin) » même si je pense qu'utiliser « d'Allemagne » dans ce cas ne serait pas totalement faux non plus.

Pour répondre à l'exemple « je viens de la Russie Profonde » :
Généralement on utilise pas le "la" lorsqu'il s'agit d'un pays, ainsi il serait plus correct de dire « je viens de Russie » plutôt que « je viens de la Russie » par exemple.
Mais dans ce cas précis, on ne parle pas "juste" de la Russie donc il semble plus correct de dire « je viens de la Russie Profonde » plutôt que de dire « je viens de Russie Profonde » cela sonne faux, car, selon moi, ce n'est pas l'appellation officielle d'un pays.

Enfin, je pense que l'article est plus souvent utilisé pour décrire l'objet (par exemple lorsque je parle de LA Russie) et plus souvent omis pour désigner une origine (« je viens d'Italie »).

Answer (score 2):

Cette distribution étrange est récurrente en français. Elle apparaît de la même façon pour *au* et *en* avec les mêmes types de noms de pays (et noms propres de lieux). On utilise, au singulier, *en* devant tous les féminins (*en France, en Italie*) et les masculins qui déclenchent l'élision (*en Iran*), et *au* devant les masculins qui ne déclenchent pas la liaison (*au Portugal*). Cette différence est neutralisée au pluriel avec la présence généralisée de *aux*.

Ce phénomène est à rapprocher de la distribution des possessifs et des démonstratifs singuliers :

- *mon, ton, son* apparaissent avec les noms masculins (*mon chat, mon oiseau*) ou avec un nom féminin devant un mot qui déclenche la liaison (*mon auto, mon adorable voisine*)
- *ma, ta, sa* apparaissent avec les noms féminins devant un mot qui ne déclenchent pas la liaison (*ma voiture, ma grande auto*)
- *ce* apparait avec les noms masculins devant un mot qui ne déclenche pas la liaison (*ce matin, ce nouvel argument*)
- *cet, cette* apparaissent avec les noms féminins (*cette matinée, cette idée*) ou avec un nom masculin devant un mot qui déclenche la liaison (*cet argument, cet ancien militaire*)

Comment: Mais ici ce n'est pas une distinction entre masculin commençant par une consonne et féminin ou commençant par une voyelle.

Comment: @Gilles Et pour Iran, vous auriez quelle intuition ? Il me semble que ça suit la même distribution pour les noms propres utilisés sans modifieurs. Pour les noms propres utilisés avec modifieurs, la différence existe au delà des toponymes, *la* Jeanne que je connais, avec l'apparition d'un déterminant...

Comment: Ben j'hésite, justement. Mais je ne penche pas d'un côté différent pour *Inde* et *Iran*.

Comment: @Gilles Inde est féminin et commence par une voyelle, et Iran commence par une voyelle, ils sont dans la même catégorie pour cette distribution : *en Inde, en Iran*

Answer (score -2):

Je ressens une différence.

"Je vis à Paris, mais je viens d'Allemagne" = j'en suis originaire.

"Mes vacances sont finies, je (re)viens d'Allemagne".

Comment: Euh, si tu ressens une différence, une des phrases devrait utiliser « de l'Allemagne », non ?

Answer (score -3):

ABC de la grammaire : le sens est prioritaire aux règles tout simplement !
je viens de l'allemagne veut dire du terroir, de l'histoire, de la vraie.
je viens d'allemagne veut dire administrativement hors des frontières d'ici.
Une distinction similaire existe pour les us; united states ou states est utilisé par les étrangers mais united states of america par les vrais citoyens américains.