# De, de la, du : why Tour de France and not Tour de la France?

Tags: articles, indications-de-lieu, noms-propres

I would like to know why it is *Tour de France*, and not *tour de la France*, given that it is *coupe du monde*.

Comment: Articles in front of names of countries or regions are sometimes weird. [I'm still wondering about another case](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne).

Answer (score 2):

I am totally unable to explain why. Both are correct indeed. When you are a tourist visiting France, I suppose it will be more correct to say: "*Je fais le tour de la France.*"

On the opposite, when you are a coach wanting your athletes to run a bit, you may yell at them: "*Vous allez me faire trois tours de terrain et plus vite que ça !*"

The slight nuance I perceive in these phrases (though I cannot find a rule to justify it as right or wrong) is this:

- when speaking of the "*tour de **la** France*", I focus on the action: I am making a circuit that makes me visit France ;
- when speaking of a "*tour de terrain*", I am actually using a unit: you are to run around the field, which is the length of your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it is a kind of possessive construction rather than a circuit description. We also have le Tour d'Espagne, le Tour d'Italie. Le Tour is a type of race.

There is a recurring problem with country names in French with *en* and *de*, feminine (France) and vowel initial (Iran) country names do not select the same constructions as masculine consonant initial (Danemark) country names:

- Paul passe ses vacances **en** France, **en** Iran ou **au** Danemark
- Pierre a couru le Tour **de** France, le Tour **d**'Iran et le Tour **du** Danemark

Comment: Mais on ne dirait pas « le tour de Luxembourg ». Ça ne marche pas pour les noms masculins (sauf s'ils commencent par une voyelle).

Comment: Tout à fait, même principe que *en France* vs *au Luxembourg*

Answer (score 1):

Mais si je suis les frontières de l'Hexagone en voiture, j'aurai fait le tour *de la* France et non le tour de France. Mais au Québec, une course de bicyclettes a déjà porté le nom de tour *du* Québec et le tour *du* Québec est ce que fera une personne qui d'autoroutes en routes nationales et traversiers fera Montréal-Sherbrooke-Gaspé-...-Montréal.

Answer (score 1):

It is a circuit description.
History recalls the reason why it is "Tour de France".
see Compagnons du Tour de France & Franc-Maçon pls.
"Mais si je suis les frontières de l'Hexagone en voiture, j'aurai fait le tour de la France" non, ce n'est pas un périmètre mais un circuit ; si tu suis les frontières ; tu n'est pas en france.
Faire le tour de la france est une expression qui a un autre sens aussi bien concrêtement qu'au figuré.
Bonjour la culture !