# Is it correct to say "la capitale de France"?

Tags: articles, indications-de-lieu

If so, is the meaning any different from that of "[la capitale de la France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitale_de_la_France)"?

More generally, why is the article omitted in other phrases, such as "Stade de France," "Tour de France" and "roi de France"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article is not used in fixed compound expressions. *Stade de France*, *Tour de France*, *Roi de France* like many other, including official ones and brands: *Collège de France*, *Banque de France*, *Gîtes de France*, *Fondation de France*, *Île-de-France*, *Patrouille de France*, *Histoire de France*, *Open de France*, *Coupe de France*, and numerous others.

On the other hand, if France is used as an individual word, there is an article. This article is mandatory if France has an adjective, otherwise, the adjective would be bound to the compound word.

- J'ai fait deux fois le tour de France. (compound, usually the cycling race)
- J'ai fait deux fois le tour de la France. (individual, might be by car or whatever)
- L'histoire de France en dix volumes (*en dix volumes* apply to the whole).
- L'histoire de la France médiévale (*médiévale* apply to France).

Should there be more than one France at the same time, we would use:

- *Roi de la France de l'ouest*

and

- *Roi de la France de l'est*

For some reason, *Capitale de France* which was less used but nevertheless coexisting with *Capitale de la France* in the past is no longer in use.

Comment: Comme mot individuel avec l'article, il y a certaines exceptions tel qu'illustré par _ambassade de France/gouvernement de la France_ en contexte de l'origine et le fait qu'on trouve aussi facilement _régions de France/de la France_. Quant à _roi_, c'est un cas particulier avec l'article manquant au singulier fém. ou avec voy. (_roi(s) de France_), mais aussi avec des noms masc. avec cons. (_roi de Portugal_). Ça dépasse le cadre de la Q...

Answer (score 1):

Pour désigner un état on ne dit pas France, Brésil, Portugal, mais *la* France, *le* Brésil, *le* Portugal.

Il faut donc l'article défini lorsque l'on parle de la capitale d'un état :

> La capitale de ***la*** France.

Comme France est aussi un prénom francophone, on pourrait dire, même si cela n'est pas fréquent :
la capitale *de France* est Bruxelles, si cette dernière est Belge, celle *de Louis* (luxembourgeois) est Luxembourg.

S'il ne s'agit pas d'un état, on rattache directement la personne ou l'entité à la France, sans l'article défini, on la place dans son  pays, dans sa région :

> La région Île de France.

... et non pas la région *de* l'Île *de* France, et encore moins : la région *de l*'Île *de la* France.

---

***EDIT***

*[Une réponse bien documentée](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne/14364#14364)* concernant l'utilisation de l'article ou non.

---

***EDIT***

Pour la France, un moyen mnémotechnique :
Si l'on peut remplacer *de ??? France* par *de l'état français*, alors on utile l'article, sinon on l'enlève

> - La Politique de *la* France (de *l'état français*).
> - la politique des partis.

Comment: La différence entre Etat et pays (au sens d'étendue géographique) est pourtant parfois ténue : "le Tour **de** France" mais "dans toute **la** France"...

Comment: @guillaume31 Le Tour de France : nom  + de + France, le Tour n'étant pas un état, suppression du *la* -- Dans [toute] la France : Préposition de lieu, normalement suivie  du lieu qu'elle désigne, la France

Comment: En parlant des choses/qualités qui ne sont pas strictement liées à l’état (politique) mais qui s’y trouvent dedans/lui appartient  (formations géographiques, par exemple), est-ce que l’on dit « les fleuves/montagnes ‘de’ (ou ‘de la’) France » ?

Comment: @PapaPoule On dit "Les fleuves de France" Cf. Ngram : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fleuves+de+France%2Cfleuves+de+la+France&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfleuves%20de%20France%3B%2Cc0 --- Toutefois on pourrait dire "Les fleuves de la France que j'aime", la France n'y est plus un pays où coule des fleuves, mais l'objet d'un amour.

Comment: @cl-r *"le Tour n'étant pas un état"*... la Capitale n'est pas un Etat non plus et pourtant on dit la capitale de **la** France... désolé mais ça ne tient pas debout

Comment: @guillaume31 J'ai complété ma question pour répondre à votre commentaire.

Comment: Je n'ai pas voté mais voir [ceci](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14364)...

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres Merci -- Votre commentaire étant masqué, j'ai intégré votre lien dans ma réponse.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's correct and both de France and de la France , but the second one is best answer.

Comment: Hello, welcome to French SE! Can you please develop the difference between them ? For instance, in which case one is better than the other. The goal is to help the OP to understand WHY it works like that.

Comment: Il faudrait développer plus votre réponse.