# Why is there no definite article in the phrase "viennent d'Afrique"?

Tags: articles

I would like to say, "The immigrants come from Maghreb and sub-Saharan Africa." So far I have,

> Les immigrés viennent du Maghreb et d'Afrique sub-saharienne.

The contracted article "du" makes sense here, but why is there no definite article before Afrique? I would expect to see either "du", "de la" or even "des" depending on gender and number. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Both are correct. [It's complicated.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne)

Comment: You say "venir d'Asie" (without an article) to refer to the entire Asian region in general, whereas for just some specific areas of the region in particular, you say (with a definite article) "venir de l'Asie du Sud-Est".

Comment: @Alone-zee Thank you! That helps, especially since the related thread is mostly in French.