# “Du Japon” but “de France”?

Tags: grammaire, genre

My French course (Rosetta Stone) has the following examples:

1. Cet homme est d’Australie
2. Cet homme est de France
3. Cet homme est de Russie
4. Cet homme est du Japon

Why the other three just use “de” but Japon has to use “du”?

Comment: C'est un vaste sujet… https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne

Comment: Note that none of those sentences is really idiomatic. We'd rather say "Cet homme vient d'Australie" or "Cet homme est australien" I think.

Comment: Il y a même des nuances dans l'usage comme _gouvernement de la France/ambassade de France_. Vraiment un sujet touffu et ça finit par déborder le seul cadre du nom du pays. Merci !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Masculine vs feminine. "de" + feminine country name vs "du" [de+le] + masculine country name.

- du Japon, du Gabon, du Pérou

NB some countries are not used with an article (so technically they have no gender), like Cuba or Puerto Rico. In which case, for "neutral" country names, it is "de + name". De Cuba, de Guernesey.

Finally, for country names that are used with the plural form, like Etats Unis, or Caraïbes, it is [de + les] = des. Des Etats Unis, des Caraïbes.

Comment: Non. Not an exception but a different case. Cuba is Cuba. Neither **le** Cuba, nor **la** Cuba. It doesn't have a gender, like Puerto Rico.

Comment: It still has a gender (masculine here), as every noun in French has a gender.

Comment: Also it doesn't work for URSS: de l'URSS

Comment: U in URSS is Union, a common noun, not a proper noun.

Comment: and so is "états" in "États Unis"

Comment: @dda : you may add Israel to the list of countries with no article like Cuba. And as it begins with a *I*, we use *d'Israel*.