# Quels sont les noms de pays qui s'emploient sans article?

Tags: noms-propres, toponymes, absence-d-article

Quels sont les pays dont le nom s'emploie sans article?

Cette question est différente de [« Je viens d'Allemagne » ou « je viens de l'Allemagne » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne) Concernant la construction qui fait l'objet de l'autre question, tous les pays ci-dessous se construisent avec *de* ou *d'*, qu'ils soient masculins ou féminins parce qu'ils ne prennent pas d'article défini.

C'est aussi une question ouverte pour lancer un quiz en société.

Comment: @jlliagre: cette question est différente. Concernant la construction qui fait l'objet de l'autre question, tous les pays ci-dessous se construisent avec *de* ou *d'*, qu'ils soient masculins ou féminins par ce qu'ils ne prennent pas d'article défini.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un certain nombre d'îles :

- Antigua-et-Barbuda
- Ceylan (mais le Sri-Lanka)
- Chypre
- Cuba
- Haïti
- Madagascar
- Malte
- Maurice
- Nauru
- Niue
- Palaos
- Saint-Christophe-et-Niévès
- Sainte-Lucie
- Saint-Vincent-et-les-Grenadines
- São Tomé-et-Principe
- Taïwan (ou Formose, pays non reconnu)
- Trinité-et-Tobago

Quelques principautés et cités-états :

- Djibouti
- Monaco
- Saint-Marin
- Singapour

Quelques rares états continentaux :

- Israël
- Oman

Il y a beaucoup d'autres exemples d'îles qui ne sont pas des états et s'emploient sans article :

- Jersey, Guernesey, Alderley
- Majorque, Minorque, Ibiza, Pantelleria
- Santorin, Delos, Paros, Corfou, Ithaque, Naxos, Samos...
- Lanzarotte, Ténériffe, Fuerte-Ventura
- Terre-Neuve, Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon
- Sainte-Hélène
- Zanzibar
- Saint-Martin, Saint-Barthélémy, Montserrat, Porto-Rico, Aruba
- Tahiti, Bora-Bora, Clipperton...
- Hawaï, Guam...
- Bornéo, Bali, Java, Sumatra