# How to say "I'm leaving France"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I was reading the following [article](https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-vocabulary/to-leave-to-exit-quitter-sortir-partir-laisser/)  about the different types of "leaving".

It is still unclear to me how to say "I am leaving France".

Google trans gives me

> Je quitte la France.

The article says I should say

> Je pars de France.

I am curious which one is the more "common/natural" translation?

Comment: Why are you leaving France?

Comment: Just example haha

Comment: *Je quitte la France* → I'm leaving France (i.e. I won't be staying there any longer). *Je pars de France*  → I'm leaving from France (i.e. it's my departure point).

Comment: @None I suggest you turn this comment into an answer, it is a valid answer IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

This article is wrong on several points. “*Je quitte la France*” and “*je pars de France*” are often interchangeable, and where they aren't the article is missing some important points.

In the sense of “I'm emigrating from France”, i..e leaving and not coming back, *quitter* is more common, but I don't think *partir* is wrong. There are [Google Books hits for “*quitte la France pour toujours*”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quitt%C3%A9+la+France+pour+toujours%22) (this includes both the present *quitte* and and the past *quitté*), but a single web hit each for [“*pars de France pour toujours*”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pars+de+France+pour+toujours%22) and [“*parti de France pour toujours*”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22parti+de+France+pour+toujours%22) and none for [“*part de France pour toujours*”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22part+de+France+pour+toujours%22). The phrase “love it or leave it”, which originated in the US, made its way to France around 2007 as “*La France, tu l'aimes ou tu la quittes*”. But despite the prevalence of *quitter*, as a native French speaker, I can't find anything wrong with “*je pars de France et je ne reviendrai jamais*”. I think that *quitter* is a bit more official or emotional, while *partir* is a bit more casual, and that makes *quitter* generally more suitable if you're leaving and not coming back.

In the sense of “I'm leaving France temporarily”, I think *quitter* and *partir* are interchangeable. I don't feel any difference between “*je quitte la France jusqu'à ce que l'affaire soit prescrite*” and “*je pars de France jusqu'à ce que l'affaire soit prescrite*” (“I'm leaving France until the statute of limitations expires”), or between “*je quitte la France pour quelques jours*” and “*je pars de France pour quelques jours*”.

In the sense of “I'm crossing the border”, the correct verb is *quitter*. In some places where a road crosses a French border, there's a sign “*vous quittez la France*” (photos: [1](https://labanmattei.photoshelter.com/image/I0000Mkvhfv012zQ), [2](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/hauts-de-france/la-frontiere-franco-belge-sous-haute-surveillance-958913.html)). Another possible verb is *sortir*. It's mostly used in legal contexts and we don't usually say “*sortir de France*”. A minor needs an [*autorisation de sortir du territoire*](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1359).

In contrast, to indicate the point of origin of a trip, the correct verb is *partir*. For example “*Le [Tour de France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_de_France#Le_Tour_de_France_%C3%A0_l'%C3%A9tranger) partira de France en 2020, mais du Danemark en 2021*” (“the Tour de France [long-distance cycling race] will start from France in 2020, but from Denmark in 2021”). Here *quitter* is clearly wrong, or more precisely it would have a different, uncommon meaning: “*le Tour de France quitte la France*” would mean that the entire race is moving to some other country (as in “*le [Paris-Dakar](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rallye_Dakar)* a quitté l'Europe et l'Afrique pour l'Amérique du Sud en 2009*”).

*Partir* is also the correct verb in the sense of “setting into motion”. I can't think of a good example with such a large area as a country. For example, “*le train part de Paris*” refers to the time when the train sets into motion in a station in Paris, whereas “*le train quitte Paris*”, strictly speaking, refers to the time when the train leaves the Paris city limits. In practice the two might be used interchangeably if *Paris* is used as a metonymy for that station. A sentence like “*le train quitte Paris à 15h24*” would indicate the time of departure from the station; it wouldn't be wrong, but “*le train part de Paris à 15h24*” is more common.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed that you say "Je quitte Paris," and "Je quitte LA France." Similarly when we use used cities /countries in google translate. What's the idea here?

Comment: @W.Zhan There's never an article in front of names of cities (except if the article is part of the name, e.g. [Le Puy](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Puy_(Doubs)). Country names can take an article, in some cases. A [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7508/358) about the use of an article in front of country names, it's in French.