# What is happening grammatically in the street name "Rue de Seine"?

Tags: grammaire, articles, toponymes, absence-d-article

Looking at a map of Paris, I stumbled on the *Rue de Seine* (in the VI Arrondissement).  I would have expected the street to be called "Rue de la Seine". I've looked for "Rue de Rhône", but I've only found various Rues du Rhône.

I'm used to names like *Rue d'Avignon*, but cities never have articles.

> Is there a grammatical principle at work here? Or is this just a street with a weird name?

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant to the "why", but according to the wikipedia article. the "rue de Seine" was originally a path leading to the Seine. In that sense, it is not the same as eg "Rue du Rhône", where the name is just a reference to the river, but with no "topological" link to it.

Comment: A few cities have articles: *la Rochelle*, *la Nouvelle-Orleans*, *le Havre*, *le Cap*, *la Mecque*, *le Puy*, *la Haye*...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

« Les noms désignant des régions (continents, pays, provinces, départements, etc.), des montagnes, des mers ou des lacs, des cours d'eau » prennent « ordinairement » l'article défini sauf que « pour les noms de cours d'eau, il reste des traces de l'ancien usage » (LBU) :

> En ancien français, on employait généralement sans article les noms de
> régions ou de cours d'eau. On pouvait dire encore au XVI<sup>e</sup>
> et au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle : *A voir couler sur Marne les bateaus*
> (RONSARD, éd. L., t. VI, p. 11 ). — *Presque tous ceux de delà Loire*
> (VAUGELAS, p. 405). — <sup>+</sup>*il est tout à fait de l'intérêt
> d'Espagne de fortifier ce parti* (LA ROCHEF., t. III, p. 85). —
> <sup>+</sup>*Ma fille est partie pour Provence* (SÉV., 31 mars 1694).
> — <sup>+</sup>*La puissance d'Autriche* (BOSS., *Or. fun.*, Le Tellier).
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> , § 588 H4 ]

Plus spécifiquement :

> [...] Autres traces avec des noms féminins. Comme compléments de noms comme *bord, rive, quai* : *Les bords
> de Durance* (GlONO, *Un de Baumugnes*, I). —
> *Les bords de Loire* (P.-H. SIMON, *Raisins verts*, p. 139). — *Les bords de Seine* (J.-P. CHEVÈNEMENT, *Les socialistes, les commun, et
> les autres*, p. 97). — *Les quais de Loire* (GENEVOIX, *Jeux de
> glace*, p. 79). — *La rue de Seine, à Paris.* [...]
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> , §
> 588 c ]

---

Yes, that's an exception to a more general usage rule whereby you will typically have the definite article with such a name (of a river).

Comment: Merci beaucoup - j'ai l'impression que ça répond définitivement à ma question.

Comment: Je viens de voir votre réponse, La vérification est faite donc ; il y a toujours un élément de libre arbitre dans la pratique anormale puisque pour tous ces cas exceptionnel des localités ont choisi de ne pas faire les modifications et de conserver les formes désuètes, si on peut les appeler ainsi.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas FYI "definitely" and "définitivement" are somewhat false friends. "sans aucun doute" ou "assurément" would have probably been a better fit in your comment. "définitivement" has a meaning of permanency/immutability : "j'ai définitivement résolu ce problème" = "I've fixed this problem once and for all"

Comment: @Aaron: thanks for this. At least it sounds as though définitivement is not pejorative! (As you correctly intuit, definitively was what I was trying to say!)

Comment: I am going to take another example: in Lyon, everybody says "les quais de Saône", not "les quais de la Saône". BUT, oddly, for the other river, nobody says "les quais de Rhône" ; it is "les quais du (=de le) Rhône"

Comment: Pour des noms de localités situées sur des cours d'eau, LBU oppose par exemple _Châlons-sur-Marne_ à des exceptions ou hésitations comme _Francfort-sur-LE-Main_. On spécule que le dernier est de formation plus récente (LBU). cc @JeanMarieBecker Bien vu pour le Rhône.

Comment: S'il fallait grouper le mot "fleuve" et le mot "Rhône", on dirait en effet "le fleuve Rhône", et non le "fleuve du Rhône", mais cela sonne "technique" ; on n'utilisera pas ce groupement, sauf dans un cours de géographie...

Comment: Au Québec, on a aussi la [_Seine_](https://toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/recherche.aspx?s=seine) ! Des trucs de formation beaucoup plus récente avec l'article ; il y a soit disant une [_Avenue de la Seine_](https://toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/Fiche.aspx?no_seq=292136) à Anjou (Montréal). Beaucoup plus loin, sur la Côte-Nord du Québec, il y a une [_Anse de Seine_](https://toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/Fiche.aspx?no_seq=3889160) mais ça réfère à l'activité de [pêche](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seine), et non au fleuve de France...

Comment: Le genre du nom propre a sûrement aussi son influence, comme pour les noms de pays: Je viens d'Allemagne, d'Angleterre, d'Italie, de Suède, de Chine (pas d'article, féminins) mais je viens du Portugal, du Yémen, du Japon, du Canada, du Mexique (présence d'un article, masculins). https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne

Comment: @jlliagre En effet, et c'est pire encore, non seulement le genre, mais aussi le sens des locution, la présence de la préposition _de_ etc. comme en témoigne : _en France, la France, l'économie de la France, un vin de France, l'ambassade de France_. Avec _je viens_ ça donne l'origine, donc sans article. Merci pour le lien, je ne me souvenais plus de cette réponse-là. On avait mis le paquet.

Answer (score 6):

The name of this street goes back to the end of the 15th century ([ref.](https://www.bercail.com/paris/75006/rue-de-seine)).
There seems to be no particular principle dictating this construction rather than the usual one ; this rather haphazard practice is found for instance (carried here to an extreme) in "Rue Garonne", a street in Agen, a city near the Garonne river. Is also found a "Rue Loire" in Saint Sébastien sur Loire ([ref.](https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/rue-loire-saint-sebastien-sur-loire-44/-)) and other places; as well, there is somewhere a "Rue de Loire". It seems,  in my opinion, for the least, that these constructions are due simply to the inhabitants' whimsies, or at best, carelessness.

Comment: Thanks for the info! For what it's worth, Google maps tells me there are other Rues de Seine in a few other places also.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Je vais voir si je peux trouver quelque chose dans LBU ; j'ai négligé trop de recherche parce qu'il ne semble pas y avoir de principe autre que l'habitude après que quelqu'un ait « donné le ton », mais je vais vérifier LBU par acquis de conscience.

Comment: @jlliagre It is clear that this situation that leaves us with exceptional forms is a socio-linguistic phenomenon, wouldn't you say? How would you call it then? It is a situation that  shows nothing more than a refusal by a very few to adopt a new practice introduced in the language, there is no grammatical principle involved. What  the other answer provides is merely some historical record of usage changes.

Comment: *A refusal by a very few to adopt a new practice introduced in the language*: Isn't it a good description of your usual attitude?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Attention, je ne prétends pas du tout faire mieux avec ma réponse, pas du tout : les faits historiques que vous avez dénichés y auraient figuré à son plus grand avantage. Ils est très important de situer d'abord la question dans ce cadre historique. Quand à la leçon de morale il n'y en a pas ; je constate seulement que des groupes très minoritaires en ont fait à leur tête ; je ne pense pas que l'on découvre quoi que ce soit de rationnel pour expliquer ça, d'où ma déduction d'une situation qui résulte de décisions subjectives. Enfin, je crois devoir dire que dans (1/2)

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse le domaine de la recherche de la vérité, il n'y a pas de gêne à avoir. (2/2)

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Oui, mon vocabulaire manque un peu de professionnalisme, je suis d'accord.

Comment: Il n'est pas trop tard pour corriger ce terme insultant pour les habitants de cette rue, si tant est qu'ils aient eu leur mot à dire...

Comment: @jlliagre Il n'y a rien d'insultant dans le mot « whimsy » ; ce n'est tout simplement pas flatteur, et puis jetez un coup d'œil à [ceci](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_autr84vWAiHFbX6w&page=9dmBsucRcXHQ.html) : une fois que l'on se débarrasse de la  personnification (peu professionnel selon ce que l'on me laisse entendre, mais instructif), qu'est-ce qu'il nous reste ?